# Can I somehow pass a parameter from a controller into $form->createView()?

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, twig, formbuilder

Can I somehow access FormView class through a controller?
I need on error to change placeholder of an input.

This is how I try to access it : (doesn't work)

```
//AnyController.php
return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
                [
                    'children' => [
                        'password' => [
                            'vars' => [
                                'attr' => [
                                    'placeholder' => 'Paswordeeeeee',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]

            ]
        );
```

[This is what I am trying to access, I got this with `dd($form->createView());`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byWH5.png)

This is more like a general question on can I access `$form->createView()` FormView class from a *controller*?

Comment: [Avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in your questions.

Comment: If all you are doing is trying to verify a password then just use a [RepeatedType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in twig like this :

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {'placeholder': form.username.vars.valid ? 'enter a username' : 'your error message'}})) }}
```

but even the username is not valid, the placeholder with the error message **will not be displayed** because in case of error, the input will be filled with text that you have typed. it.
you can see it only if you empty the input.

So, I think that what you want to do, has no sens.

Comment: I edited my post, I want to change password placeholder from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this.

```
//AnyController.php
return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
                [
                    'children' => [
                        'password' => [
                            'vars' => [
                                'attr' => [
                                    'placeholder' => $form->isValid() ? 'valid placeholder' : 'invalid placeholder',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]

            ]
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
dump($form->getErrors());
exit();
```

You should use exit() because it will stop the program.

> dump(...);exit()

It will work just like dd() in Laravel.

Comment: This is Symfony.